# upload file on server using FTP

Tags: magento2

I am uploading XML file using $ftp->write function.

And in that function where I can pass a directory path where I want to upload my file on server?

Please advise

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. Otherwise people will mark your question unclear.

Comment: I have created custom XML file into a local server and connect FTP using programmatically in Magento 2

Now I want to upload that generated xml file into FTP server in specific locaation.

File  successfully uploaded into root directory but I need to upload in a particular directory

How I can archive this?

Comment: Please advice for the above question